# Cómo comparar horas en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito comparar la hora que obtengo desde un atributo en html. Les adjunto mi código:

```
che=($(this).attr("data-horario"));
currentTime = new Date();
currentTime = currentTime.getHours() +":"+ currentTime.getMinutes()+":"+currentTime.getSeconds()

console.log(che);
console.log(currentTime );
           
if (che > currentTime) {
    console.log("es mayor el che"+ che);
} else{
    console.log("es menor el che"+ che);
```

Necesito saber si el horario de cuando se ejecuta la función es mayor o menor del horario en el que se puede ejecutar...

A lo que me refiero es a lo siguiente: si en el horario del check es 10:50, y el horario actual son las 10, puede ejecutar acciones, pero si son 5 min, antes de lo que dice el check ejecuta otro código.

> Todos los checkbox los lleno desde una base de datos.

Comment: Agrega che a tu código porque me lanza el siguiente error: Uncaught ReferenceError: che is not defined

Comment: si seguranmente, ya que esa variable la obtengo de los atributos de un checkbox

Comment: esto no tiene nada que ver con php segun veo tu codigo y esto: console.log es una ejecucion netamente en javascript

Comment: si porque desea ver si ejecutaba el if, los checkbox los cargo con php con el siguiente codigo

`$inf.='<div class="form-check">';
      $inf.='<input class="form-check-input " type="checkbox" value="'.$row['nombre'].'" id="'.base64_encode($row['id_loteria']).'" name="'.base64_encode($row['id_loteria']).'"  data-horario="'.$row["horario"].'">';
      $inf.='<label class="form-check-label" for="">';
      $inf.=$row['abreviatura'] .' - '.$row['horario'] ;
      $inf.='</label>';
      $inf.='</div>';`

Answer (score 0):

Para compara fecha ambas variables tiene que ser de tipo **Date**

```
const cheDate = new Date(che);
      const currentTimeDate = new Date(currentTime);

      if (cheDate > currentTimeDate) {
        console.log("es mayor el che" + che);
      } else {
        console.log("es menor el che" + che);
      }
```

Comment: estoy realizando esto
`timeImput=($(this).attr("data-horario")).split(":");
                timeNow = new Date();
                timeNow = timeNow.getHours()+":"+ timeNow.getMinutes()+":"+timeNow.getSeconds();
                valTime = new Date();
                valTime= valTime.setHours(timeImput[0])+":"+valTime.setMinutes(timeImput[1])+":"+valTime.setSeconds(timeImput[2]);`

pero el set me da el siguiente valor : 1659448489414 cuando hago un log

Comment: Si el resultado es de tipo Date, debiera tener algún método para mostrar el valor usando el formato que elijas.
O puedes usar los métodos para extraer valores por separado como getFullYear(), getMonth(), getDate(), getHours(), y mostrarlo como quieras.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en `currentTime = currentTime.getHours() +`... estas convertiendo un objeto Date a un Objeto String.
Para comparar Date, debe ser entre Objetos Date, Puedes convertirlo a String para mostrarlo, no para operar.

```js
che=new Date("1/2/2012");
currentTime = new Date();
currentTimeString = currentTime.getHours() +":"+ currentTime.getMinutes()+":"+currentTime.getSeconds();

console.log(che);
console.log(currentTimeString );
           
if (che > currentTime) {
    console.log("es mayor el che "+ che);
} else{
    console.log("es menor el che "+ che);
    }
```